# Binding javascript code to android code with objects parameters

Tags: javascript, android, web-applications, webview, android-webview

As the title suggests, I'm trying to bind javascript code to my android app so I can react in my app to an event/message that my website is sending.

After reading the official [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) related to javascript binding I managed to easily implement it.. as long as it's a string.

What is working fine? 
I implemented the following code in my app:

```
/** Instantiate the interface and set the context  */
class ClientInterface(private val mContext: Context) {

    /** Show a toast from the web page  */
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun postMessage(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

if the parameter of the 'postMessage' function is a String and I'm passing a String from my javascript as a parameter, everything is fine. it's passing the string.
my problem is that I am trying to get a JSONObject instead of a String, and it's not working.
I tried casting everything I thought might work.. JSONObject / JSONObject? / Any / Any? / Object / Object? and so on..

when I'm sending an object on my javascript, nothing seems to work. all I get in my app is a null response.

anyone ever tried something like that? what am I missing?

P.S - here's my javascript code for reference:

```
var objectMessage = {
        type: "quote",
        code: "My name is Inigo Montoya. You killed my father, prepare to die!"
    }

window.CLIENT.postMessage(objectMessage);
```

Comment: try to return Json object from javascript with JSON.stringify(obj); and receive it as string on your Android code, then parse it to your object.

Comment: Did you register the ClientInterface class as JSInterface in the webview?

Comment: @TheDude Yup. I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass an object only primitive!
So you need to stringify your object.

```
var objectMessage = {
  type: "quote",
  code: "My name is Inigo Montoya. You killed my father, prepare to die!"
}

window.CLIENT.postMessage(JSON.stringify(objectMessage));
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not possible? Is it written anywhere? documented somewhere?

Comment: Yes i'm sure, try it.